# Keep having to do renew dns

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ipconfig

I've just had to buy a new Windows PC as a temporary replacement for a mac in repair. Everything is fine, with one small annoyance. Every now and then (i.e. every couple of hours, no pattern though), I have to do an ipconfig /renew.

I also have to do that every time that I shut down or hibernate the machine. Any idea why this would happen, or how to fix it?

Running Windows 7, HP Pavilion dm1 notebook PC.

Cheers.

Comment: How is the IP and other network settings assigned?

Comment: Auto generated as far as TCP/IP settings are concerned on the devices' properties, is that what you mean?

Comment: I wonder if the loaner PC has spyware/monitoring software installed causing this. Most HP's have a recovery partition to restore it to the original HP Windows install, might be worth restoring it...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01895783&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en#RestoreWithoutWindows

Comment: It's not a loan machine, bought new and installed from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There are online reports of DHCP autorenew failures on Windows 7 dating back to mid-2009 at least.  Since you bought a new system you might check to make sure your Windows patches are up-to-date.  The next thing to try is turning off Wake-on-LAN in your Ethernet adapter config, as there is a report of this curing the problem.

Comment: Seems to have made a difference. I still have to renew every now and then, but it's doing a lot better after updates. Will try wake on lan config next.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, even with updates there were still problems. I set the DNS in the TCP/IP v.4 router settings to use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, and that has worked an absolute treat. Job done.